# using input to capture random questions in a folder

Tags: input, random

I have a directory with multiple questions, each question has a number, example, quest1 ... questn.
Using random numbers I want to get the questions randomly, I'm using `\input {}` because the questions are written in LaTex.

Here's how to generate the random numbers:

```
%% get random integer
\newcommand\randomint[2]{\bgroup%
     \pgfmathsetmacro\myval{randomfixed(#1,#2)}
     \pgfmathsetmacro\end{(\myval<0)?"(\myval)" \myval}
     \end\egroup}%%
```

Following the call with `\input {}`:

```
\def \nror{\randomint {1} {20}}
\input {../questoesCPP/cmdEN/questao\nror}

The idea would be:
\input {../questoesCPP/cmdEN/questao1}
\input {../questoesCPP/cmdEN/questao7}
\input {../questoesCPP/cmdEN/questao15}
...
```

but the `\input {}` acknowledges error, I do not know what it is:

> Extra}, or forgotten \endgroup. \input {../questoesCPP/cmdEN/questao\nror}

Please count on your help, thank you very much.
airton

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can highlight code in your post using back-ticks. To highlight code-blocks, either indent them by four spaces or use the `{}` on the gui. Can you please expand the code snippet that you have posted to a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). A MWE should  be as *small as possible* to demonstrate your problem. it's much easier to help you if we have close to working code to start from.

Comment: The snippets that you posted were hard to read as they were not formatted properly. Perhaps I changed something when I (tried to?) fix this? What is currently there will certainly not work as you have `\pgfmathsetmacro\end{...}` BUT you can't use `\end` like this as it's an important LaTeX command. Try something like `\pgfmathsetmacro\myend{...}` instead.